# Using Maven with Neo4j User-Defined Procedures

Tags: java, maven, neo4j, mvn-repo, neo4j-java-api

I copied this github repository as a template for using User-Defined Procedures in Neo4j.

https://github.com/maxdemarzi/medicare

I added some procedures, used "mvn clean package", and was able to see these procedures in my database after putting the .jar file into the var/lib/neo4j/plugins folder and running "call dbms.procedures();" in the cypher-shell. However, when I add more functions to the database, I am not able to see or access them. Also, I can not edit or delete the procedures that I added the first time I ran "mvn clean package". Has anyone else run into this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After troubleshooting, I found that if you change the `artifactId` in the pom.xml file every time you want to recompile the jar file, it updates with the new procedures.

For example, the original `artifactId` for the medicare repository is "medicare". When I changed this value to "medicare123", ran `mvn clean package`, put the `.jar` file into the `/var/lib/neo4j/plugins` folder, and restarted my neo4j instance: I could see the procedures with the `dbms.procedures()` command in the cypher-shell. This is probably not the official way to solve this problem, but this is what fixed mine.

Comment: Did you try changing the `version` instead of the `artifactId`?